# SQLAlchemy: Map multiple instances to the same row

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relational-database

Consider Many-to-One relationship: Article-to-Keyword.
An article has only one keyword, single keyword can be referenced by multiple articles.

```
class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('keyword.id'))
    keyword = relationship("Keyword")

class Keyword(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'keyword'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Now, I'd like to be able to associate multiple instances of `Keyword` having the same `name` value
with the sole row in `keyword` table.

So that saving `a1` and `a2`:

```
a1 = Article()
a1.keyword = Keyword(name="science")

a2 = Article()
a2.keyword = Keyword(name="science")
```

Wouldn't yield unique constraint violation.

Currently one has to create additional query fetching FK from `keyword` table and set it in `Article` object as `Article.keyword_id`.

Gets pretty boring with real-world schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Unique Object](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject) recipe.